# Formatting a hex

Tags: java, string, format, hex

I have a integer, which I am trying to convert to a hex, and then pad with leading 0s so that the length of the string is 16 characters Below is my code

```
long longdpid = Long.parseLong(dataPathID);
String stringhexdpid = Long.toHexString(longdpid);
String.format("%016x", stringhexdpid);
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "POLLtimer" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
```

Could someone explain where my mistake is?

Comment: Just `String.format("%016X", longpid)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that `String.format` will do the conversion to hex for you. You don't need to call `Long.toHexString()` yourself. The format code `x` you are using requires an integer, not a string.
Read more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

`%x` takes an integer not a String

```
String.format("%016x", longdpid);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringhexdpid = Long.toHexString(longdpid);
```

After you do that you have a `String`

However in

```
String.format("%016x", stringhexdpid);
```

You are telling it to expect a long.  What you want is `'%016s'`, but that does not work since `%s` doesn't do left-padding.

To solve the problem, just do

```
String.format("%016x", longdpid);
```

Answer (score 0):

In String.format(), Just try  longdpid instead of stringhexdpid. This should work.